# Enable kafka client metrics in spring app prometheus

Tags: apache-kafka, grafana, spring-kafka

I have an application that consumes from kafka topics and produce to kafka topics. I am trying to set up Grafana dashboard to display kafka metrics. I am trying to expose the kafka metrics to prometheus and so Grafana dashboard can fetch these metrics and display them further.

Below are the libraries and properties I am using.

```
org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:2.5.1:compile
io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:jar:1.5.4:compile
io.micrometer:micrometer-jersey2:jar:1.5.4:compile
```

application properties:

```
spring.jmx.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=prometheus
management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true
management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled=true
```

Using micrometer, the prometheus is displaying jvm, tomcat related metrics and also the custom metrics. But the kafka metrics are not being exposed. I tried to debug and left with no clue. Any suggestions would be a great help.

As a heads-up, I am not using spring kafka annotations. I am running it as standalone multi-threaded where I fetch records using `consumer.poll(1000L)` method.

kafka consumer is created as: `new KafkaConsumer<>(getProps())` and kafka producer is created as `new KafkaProducer<>(props)`

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, ...);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, config.getConsumerName());

props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, config.getGroupId());
props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, config.getKeyDeserializer());
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, config.getValueDeserializer());
props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, config.getEnableAutoCommit());
props.put(ConsumerConfig.RECEIVE_BUFFER_CONFIG, config.getReceiveBufferBytes());
props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, config.getMaxPartitionFetchBytes());
props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, config.getMaxPollRecords());
props.put(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG, RoundRobinAssignor.class.getName());

protected KafkaConsumer<byte[], Event> getConsumer(List<String> inputTopics) {
    KafkaConsumer<byte[], Event> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props));
    consumer.subscribe(inputTopics, new ConsumerRebalanceListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
            logger.info("PARTITIONS revoked: " + partitions);
            consumer.commitAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
            logger.info("PARTITIONS assigned: " + partitions);
        }
    });
    return consumer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I already answered you on Gitter - the code above is not using Spring for Apache Kafka, you are creating your own consumer and producer.

If you use Spring for Apache Kafka's `DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory`, you can add a `MicrometerConsumerListener` to it and Spring will register metrics for each consumer with the meter registry via the `KafkaClientMetrics`. If you create your own consumers, you have to do that yourself.

Same thing for producers.

Comment: thank you Gary, I will check if I can change it to spring-kafka to fetch these metrics